# NSSM not starting a simple service

Tags: node.js, mongodb, batch-file, windows-services

I have following in a windows batch file, that I want to execute at startup, so I have created a service using [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/).

```
start /min cmd /k
mongod --dbpath "D:\weather_station\weather_data" --repair
mongod --dbpath "D:\weather_station\weather_data"
```

I do this to start the mongodb server for my nodejs application.

I get an error:

```
Unexpected status SERVICE_PAUSED in response to START control
```

and in the files for I/O redirection (nssm logs), I get "'mongod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."

Now this script runs fine, if I directly execute it from windows, and mongod is installed and works fine.

I dont know, why nssm wont open a new command prompt and execute this service.

Is this the best way to start the mongodb server as a windows service ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line with `start /min cmd /k` is completely useless in my point of view. Remove it.

A batch file is executed by the application defined in environment variable **ComSpec**. **ComSpec** has usually the value `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`. The command `start` is (nowadays) an internal command of `cmd.exe` to start an application as a separate process.

You use `start` to start one more `cmd.exe` with the option to keep the minimized window open even after all applications started by this command line process finished. So all you get with the first line is a new minimized command prompt window doing nothing than waiting for user input.

`cmd.exe` used to execute the commands in the batch file continues immediately parsing the second command line which begins with `mongod`.

`mongod` is not an internal command of `cmd.exe`. Therefore `mongod` is interpreted by `cmd.exe` as the name of an executable file.

But this file name of the executable is without file extension and without path. So `cmd.exe` must search for an executable.

The environment variable **PATHEXT** contains a list of file extensions separated by semicolons for executables. This list is used now to find `mongod.com` or `mongod.exe` or `mongod.bat` or `mongod.cmd`, ...

So my first advice for you is: Specify `mongod` with file extension, i.e. `mongod.exe`

As there is no file path, `cmd.exe` searches first in current working directory for `mongod.com` or `mongod.exe` or ... and next in all directories specified in environment variable **PATH** separated by semicolons.

**PATH** contains a list of directories. But there is not only one **PATH**. There is system **PATH** and a **PATH** for the current user account as it can be seen in [Advanced system settings in Windows Control Panel](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson7/) after clicking on button to open the dialog for viewing and changing the environment variables.

The **PATH** used by all applications is a combination of system **PATH** and used user account **PATH**.

You get the error message

```
'mongod' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

as the directory containing `mongod.exe` is either listed in user **PATH** of your user account, or could be found in current working directory on running the batch file manually by you. But `mongod.exe` is not specified in system **PATH** nor **PATH** of the account used to run this batch file as service. And the working directory on execution of the batch file as service is also a different one, usually `C:\Windows\System32` to get working batch files if just standard applications of Windows are specified in the batch file without file extension and file path.

The solution is therefore quite simple:

Specify `mongod.exe` with full path and in double quotes if the path contains one or more spaces.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\whatever\mongod.exe" --dbpath "D:\weather_station\weather_data" --repair
"C:\Program Files (x86)\whatever\mongod.exe" --dbpath "D:\weather_station\weather_data"
```

If `mongod` is a console application and not a GUI application, and `mongod` itself also does not start a separate process and then terminates immediately before this separate process finished, you do not need anything else. The batch file with those 2 lines is all you need.

Otherwise you would perhaps need:

```
start "Repair Data" /min /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\whatever\mongod.exe" --dbpath "D:\weather_station\weather_data" --repair
start "..." /min /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\whatever\mongod.exe" --dbpath "D:\weather_station\weather_data"
```

For help on command `start` enter in a command prompt window `help start` or `start /?`.

As a beginner in writing batch files take a look on Microsoft article about the [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands).